# How to prevent file declared in <form action="process-form.php"> from showing results to users when form is submitted?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form with a form-handler 'process-form.php. This form works as planned, however, whenever the form is submitted, before redirecting the user to another URL, (say, thank-you.html) it is showing the contents received from the form in process-form.php. How can I prevent that from happening?

```
if ($mail->send())
{

?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    alert('Message Sent!');
    window.location.replace("thank.html");
    </script>
<?php

}
else
{
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('ERROR!');</script>";
}
```

Comment: We need to see what else is happening in your `process-form.php` file. It shouldn't display anything unless you've told it to.

Comment: You could try putting your redirection logic in the handler. Or is that code in your handler already? But, you don't want to display anything to the screen from within the handler or it won't relocate. ( Hint: alert() )

Comment: You could also put your alerts in the thank.html or failed.html.

Comment: @PaddyHallihan Hey paddy, I'm new to stack overflow, therefore, I'm not sure how to share more of my code. Is there any way for me to attach a file or something? In essence, nothing out of the ordinary is happening, I'm just getting data from a form and using PHPMailer to send the actual email. However, If I don't fill a field that is not required, it shows me that it is an undefined variable, which makes sense, but I do not want the user to see that bit. Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: @nocturns2 Hey nocturns, placing alerts in the thank-you.html seems like a solution, however, I just want to display an alert to indicate to the user that the message was sent properly, and then redirect them to another page. The  thank-you.html example was just to exemplify the redirection bit.

Comment: Maybe 'Try' 'Catch' blocks? in the try block, if the code fails, execution gets passed to the catch block, where you have some control over what happens next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey so the issue you're seeing is that not all form fields are filled in so that you get an undefined variable error and you don't want users to see that.

Usually in a production environment (like my shared server) errors are hidden anyway just not on my localhost. To hide the errors though you can just use this:

```
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

However, You'd be much better off making sure there was no error in the first place. To do this check if the fields were actually filled in otherwise set your variable equal to  nothing so technically it will still exist even if it is blank.

```
if(isset($_POST['my_var'])){
    $my_var = $_POST['my_var'];
}else{
    $my_var = "";
}
```

You can also use the same `if(isset())` logic where you are actually using the variables rather than where you set them

Comment: P.S. your question wasn't very clear the code you showed is not where the issue is. In future try to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

You mean shown in the URL, or is it in the HTML of the page? If it is the former, you can use

```
<form method="POST" ...>
```

If you mean the latter, you should change your PHP / JavaScript to not show the data